# How to disable notifications when certain programs are open?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have the google hangouts extension in chrome so that I get notifications when someone calls or texts me, which is generally nice, but extremely annoying when I play starcraft.

Answer (score 0):

To perform that manually, close the Chrome Browser, then open Task Manager with {Ctrl-Alt-Del}, and close all Chrome processes.

A script to automate it, as *harrymc* kindly suggested, would look like this:

```
echo off  
c:  
taskkill /im chrome.exe  
cd \Progra~1\Starcraft  
starcraft
```

Please substitute the real path to the Starcraft executable on the 4th line
and the name of the executable file to launch Starcraft on the 5th line. The 3rd line is what kills all the Chrome processes.

I'd suggest you put that script in the Starcraft executable directory, then add a shortcut, and move the shortcut to your desktop for convenience.

Comment: I want it to work automatically though, instead of having to do that every time before I open starcraft.

Comment: +1 No point in downvoting a good answer. Just execute a `.bat` file that does `taskkill /im chrome.exe` and then starts starcraft.

Comment: troricleba, please click on [edit] and add that specification to the original question, so everyone can see it.